# what is og: in meta content of site?

Tags: seo, facebook-opengraph

How to use og in meta of a website. I have seen in many sites like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Art And Artistic - Its All About Your Talent." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://artandartistic.com/" />
```

Is it helps in SEO?

Answer (score 0):

See:

- [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/)
- [Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects)

You can also peruse the [Structured Data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en&ref_topic=4600154) topic on Google Webmasters which touches on this and [Schema.org](http://schema.org).

Comment: what is difference in 
<meta property="og:title" content="Its Title" /> and <meta name="og:title" content="Its Title" /> ??

Comment: AFAIK, it's not "different", rather [extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax)

Comment: @ErMayank: The first one is using HTML5+RDFa, the second one plain HTML5.